# Which parts of speech do the following words belong to?

Tags: prepositions, adverbs, parts-of-speech

1. Who does he live **with**?
2. The kids are playing **outside**.
3. I couldn't find anyone to talk **to**.
4. She died on the 5th and was buried the day **after**.

Comment: They're prepositions. Which some misguided pedants used to say we *shouldn't use to end sentences **with***, so they'd have you write *With who does he live?, The kids are outside playing, I couldn't find anyone with whom to talk, She died on the 5th and the day after was buried.*

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Do we seriously use the sentences in the format you have specified? I am used to hearing and using the sentences like Joshua has written.

Comment: Ah, I thought they were *adverbs*. So, would you say those particular prepositions don't have objects?

Comment: I would say that (2) and (4) are adverbs, while (1) and (3) are prepositions.  There is sometimes disagreement about grammarians about how best to classify things, though.

Comment: I think 2 is an adverb, but I think 4 might be  working as a postposed adjective.

Comment: @Dhanishtha Ghosh: Seriously? Not really! Though I'm just noticing as I look again at what I wrote that my first example is *completely* wrong. [*With **whom** does he live?*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22With+whom+does+he+live%22)

Comment: In modern grammar they are all prepositions.

Comment: Isn't there an argument for 'the day after' being treated as a semi-fixed expression which behaves like an adverb in this case, i.e. that the phrase as a whole is modifying the verb 'was buried'.

Comment: @kandyman That's a fair point.

Comment: @kandyman No: "the day after" is a noun phrase with "day" as head, and the prep "after" as complement of "day". "After" is called a stranded preposition because it is not followed by the noun phrase that is understood as its complement (in this case "the fifth").